# Unable to use SevenZFile at Java6 to unzip 7z File

Tags: java, compression, unzip, 7zip

I can unzip 7z File by using org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.SevenZFile at Java 7 and java 8. But I cant do that by using Java6. Can you please help me to fix that issue by Java 6 ? SeekableByteChannel cannot be found by Java6 :(

You can find out the sample code below :

```
SeekableInMemoryByteChannel inMemoryByteChannel = new 
 SeekableInMemoryByteChannel(targetArray);
    SevenZFile sevenZFile = new SevenZFile(inMemoryByteChannel);
```

Comment: As you can see in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SeekableByteChannel.html) the interface `SeekableByteChannel` exists since Java 7. If your library depends on it, it won't work with Java 6. Maybe there is an older library version which works under Java 6?

Comment: that means it is not possible to use SeekableByteChannel with Java6. I have to find another unzip library for that ?

Comment: `SeekableByteChannel` is part of the Java SDK but not until Java 7. This means that your library doesn't work with Java 6. But you can look for a prior version of the same library which runs under Java 6. Apache projects usually provide downloads for older versions.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Apache Commons Compress 1.13 it requires Java 7 at runtime. If you need support for Java6 version 1.12 or earlier will work (but may have less features or a different set of bugs).

In the case of 7z 1.12 and earlier only allow reading of files, not arbitrary streams. It was the move to Java7 and the chance to use `SeekableByteChannel` that allowed supporting reading from more general inputs.